# IBM Z Zowe Mainframe issue

Tags: cobol

I am doing the learning Cobol programming with VScode

Ive tried restarting VS and re entering the steps.

In LAB 2 after step 12 there are more inputs that are not in the guide and if you do not fill in those inputs it cancels the whole profile creation. And if you just press enter without putting anything in you will get

Error: z/OSMF REST API Error: | Rest API failure with HTTP(S) status 500 | category: 6 | rc:       8 | reason:   513 | message:  fopen() failed | details:  |   - EDC5041I An error was detected at the system level when opening a file. (errno2=0xC00A0022) |   - __amrc: __last_op=401 __code=0x00080098 |

I have no idea how to solve this and Ive googled it with almost not a single hit. If anyone can pinpoint or just point me in the right direction I would be most appreciative.

Comment: what dos this have to do with the editor you use to write the code

Comment: @rioV8 [Learning COBOL programming with VSCode](https://www.ibm.com/blogs/ibm-training/free-course-announcing-learning-cobol-programming-with-vscode/) is the name of the course.

Comment: HTTP 500 indicates something wrong with the server. The message suggests is an error when opening a file. Maybe you can add a self-containing example showing the problem?

Comment: @bereal Clearly the question is not related to the editor, the poster does not mention that he has no problem when using vim or emacs or notepad++, REST API failure has nothing to do with the editor, don't tag the question with irrelevant tags, yes more people use VSC than cobol, but a lot of them will be of no help

Comment: You should join the community on IBM Zxplore, and ask there. They know the details of the LABs, and how to solve problems.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this course on my side and you're right, the LAB 2 instructions are missing 6 other inputs that you will be prompted to provide when creating a new connection under Zowe Explorer.

In this case, follow the instructions on the LAB 2 up to step 12, for example:

- Create new connection
- Connection name: LearnCOBOL (or anything else you want)
- Profile type: zosmf
- URL: https://192.86.32.250:10443
- User Name: which starts with Z, and you received by e-mail when registering
- Password: which you can get following the e-mail instructions, talking to the Zih_COBOL bot on Slack
- And select "False - Accept connections with self-signed certificates"

Then simply hit Enter for all the other inputs, to use the default values (blank for most), and the connection will be defined without issues.

On my side, these were the ones that I was prompted to fill, and I just hit Enter:

- The file path to a certificate file to use for authentication
- The file path to a certificate key file to use for authentication
- The base path for your API mediation layer instance
- The protocol used (http or https)
- The encoding for download and upload of z/OS data set and USS files
- The maximum amount of time in seconds the z/OSMF Files TSO servlet should run before returning a response.